# Why do we take rectangular plates in the capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

We can take square, rectangular or circular plates in a capacitor. Why do we take rectangular plates in the capacitor?

Comment: Because it looks purty.

Comment: Sir, i think that there is some reason...

Comment: Are you talking about the circuit symbol, ore about the physical realization? In both cases, provide an example (picture).

Comment: Assuming what you say is true (big assumption), it must be optimal in some sense, like most overlap you can cram into a small package.

Comment: This question makes no sense.  First, talk of "taking" plates in a capacitor makes no sense.  Second it is supposing that that capacitors are rectangular when in reality they come in all kinds of shapes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're rectangular if you have to roll them up into a cylinder - like those rolled cakes - and need a lot of capacitance in a reasonable package.

[image: Electrolytic]

But they aren't always rectangular. The little circular ones (eg: 100nF ceramic) are, well, circular

[image: Ceramic disk]